# Logging in Java, file not create

Tags: java, file, logging

I want to perform logging. I created a class, but this class does not create a file.

This class for logging:

```
public class Log {
private static File logFile = new File("log.txt");
public Log() {
    if (!logFile.exists()) {
        try {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void write(String msg) {
    writeInFile(createString(msg));
}

private static String createString(String msg) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
    sb.append(MyDate.currentDate()).append("\t| ").append(msg);
    return sb.append('\n').toString();
}

private static void writeInFile(String msg) {
    try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile,
            true))) {
        out.write(msg);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static class MyDate {
    public static String currentDate() {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm.ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return formatter.format(date);
    }
}}
```

And I add `Log.write("some text for log");` in diferent methods

Comment: Why do you want to implement this yourself instead of just using a logging library like i.e. logback?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also, are you sure you're looking for the file in the correct folder?

Comment: i am do search in folder with my project but filr log.txt not found(

Comment: I need to use my own class for logging

Comment: Did you look for the file in the [canonical location](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath--) ?

Comment: thanks,  jmehrens.  i am write  `private static File logFile = new File("C:\\log.txt");`   and all work right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [canonical path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath--) location for the file. The code that you have depends on the current working directory.